# JDT: Replace one type for another in eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-jdt

I'm developing an eclipse plug-in that performs some code transformations. One of the tasks I have to perform is to locate all uses of the type `ArraList<?>` and replace them by the type `Vector`.

To locate classes using `ArrayList`, I'm reading each class imports and search for `java.util.ArrayList`. I know [how to change the imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6671977/how-to-redefine-an-import-using-eclipse-jdt-core), but I can't find information on how to change all `ArrayList` references.

Comment: You need to get the AST and then iterate over all the nodes. I hesitate to spend more time on answering your question since I wonder who in the world would want to use `Vector` ...

Comment: I ask myself the same. The answer is JADE http://jade.tilab.com/. To ease your mind, I made a tool that is based on JADE and I use ArrayList. For compatibility purposes, though, I need to convert my ArrayLists to JADE-friendly Vectors...

Comment: Ah, a dependency problem. How about taking the sources for JADE and doing the opposite transformation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to walk the AST, find all variable and field declarations and change the type.

This question contains pointers how to start with writing refactoring plugins: [Writing a new refactoring plugin for Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1314208/writing-a-new-refactoring-plugin-for-eclipse)

Answer (score 1):

One alternative way to convert your `ArrayLists` into `Vectors` could be to create your own `org.you.Vector` that extends `java.util.ArrayList`.

Then, as you pointed out that you are able to manipulate the imports, just replace `org.you.Vector` with `java.util.Vector`.

Comment: This is an interesting approach. Not the most elegant, but would suit my needs very much. I accepted Aaron's because it answers the question, and I can't accept both. But your solution is probably the best one for my problem. Thanks.